# SVN Protocol for fast local checkouts

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

we have a compile server which runs our SVN Server (currently Visual SVN) and also does nightly builds. The local checkout on the server takes several minutes. I am looking for ways to improve that.

Which protocol provides the fastest SVN server access?

Note: security is a concern on the server. If the fast protocol doesn't have the same security level as HTTPS, we may try to use the fast protocol for local checkouts only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) for building. Jenkins can automate the building and builds can be triggered automatically by either doing a build after each commit, or at a particular time (or both!). For example, you could say "*Build the application at 7pm each and every night*". Even better, you could give a quiet period, so the build won't start until everyone is finished. Sort of like saying "*build the application at 7pm every night, but only after 30 minutes of no one checking in any code*".

Even better, Jenkins can usually figure out what files were changed by the build process, and what files were created, then revert those files. Jenkins can then do an *update* instead of a *checkout* which will be much faster.

I bet the main problem isn't necessarily being your nightly build taking too long to checkout, but that someone has to sit their and run the build. Since Jenkins automatically runs the build, then reports its status via email, no one has to really sit around and watch the build take place.

As to the answer to your question:

- `http://` and `https://` are the slowest since all checkouts occur through Apache server. However, `http://` is probably the most popular protocol because of its flexibility.
- `svn://` and `svn+ssh://` are faster, but not quite as common as `http://`.
- `file://` is the fastest, but can only be used on the server, and it uses file level security to say who can check in or out files. It should never be used by groups of people since any user who has checkin and checkout access also has direct access to the files directly under the repository directory. Normally, users are kept off the Subversion server, and the repository directory is owned and writable (and sometimes made readable) only by the user running the Subversion process.

Some sites put Jenkins on their Subversion server, and then use the `file://` protocol to do their checkouts. Just make sure that the process that runs Jenkins also runs your Subversion server.

Answer (score 2):

`file:///` protocol, I suppose. And maybe not full checkout, but update will be usable for you in your case?

> If the fast protocol doesn't have the same security level as HTTPS

`file:///` **does NOT have ANY security at all!**

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

1. keep copy of the repository on the build server
2. keep it up to date with `svnsync`
3. use it for checkouts

This should solve the problem is size of changes is significantly less than size of a checkout (likely it is). Even if not, running svnsync more frequently, will move time for synchronization into background, so build time will decrease anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I will assume that the operation is long (several minutes) because you have a large numbers of files (or a large content).

To avoid a costly checkout (time), you can do

1. `svn revert` to revert the local changes
2. `svn update` to get the update to the latest version

Whatever the protocol you use, this technique is **quite similar to a checkout, but very fast.**